# How long will it take me to find the starting weapons I don't choose?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Before your first mission after the opening mission, I'm given the choice of four weapons:

- Stun Gun
- Tranquilizer Rifle
- Combat Rifle
- Revolver

One factor I'm considering is how long it will take my to find the weapons I do not choose, since ideally I would like to get my hands on them all at some point.

How long into the game am I able to retrieve each of these weapons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combat rifle is probably the easiest to get to. Almost every soldier, even at the start, will carry one.

A revolver is also carried by some soldiers, but less frequently, so I would put that on number two. It still won't take too long into the game though.

The first I've seen a stun gun was also somewhere in the early game, when I started for pacifist.

Seeing as I've had a tranquillizer rifle from the start, I've never bothered to look for one, but they are also present quite a bit in the first few missions.

To sum up, I don't think you'll have to wait long for any of the weapons, but the ones for up close are going to take a bit longer than the ones with distance.

Answer (score 7):

- Stungun - You can find one after completing the first mission. It's in a storage locker locked in an alleyway near Jensen's apartment. A hacking level of two is required to open it.
- Tranq - There are a couple of storage lockers in Detroit, also see the arms dealers.
- Combat Rifle - Soldiers and better armed gang members. Also look in your apartment for a few.
- Revolver - Some soldiers at the Milwaukee Junction factory may have them. I know they are found in Highland Park for sure though. (thanks @ArdaXi).

Comment: Soldiers in the plant carry revolvers before you even get to Detroit.

Comment: Huh, I mussed have missed that guy. Will update.

Comment: Am I able to get the stun gun right after I finish the first mission, Back in the Saddle?

Comment: @Wipqozn Before getting in the VTOL. See solution above.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about the Stungun. I checked, but it doesn't contain one. It does contain a weapon upgrade though.

Comment: I know there is a stungun in there, but maybe it is scripted to spawn later.

Comment: The [wiki](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Stun_gun) seems to agree with you. I'll check again.

Comment: I was looking around online, and it would appear that it is scipted to spawn later. However you can find a Stun Gun immedialy after finishing the first mission in a storage room near Jensans apartment. I've modified your answer to reflect this.